# Reverse engineering a Visual Basic p-code binary

Tags: decompilation, visual-basic

p-code is the intermediate code that was used in Visual Basic (before .NET). I would like to know where I can find resources/tools related to analysis of these virtual machine codes.

Comment: about P32Dasm , on their page, they mention "IDA Visual Basic debugger plugin" for debugging with IDA , but this plugin is impossible to find... does anyone know about this?

Comment: Here's an old RE-Reddit thread asking a similar question http://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/djhb7/tools_for_reversing_vb/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alex Ionescu, co-author of the latest "Windows Internals" book and contributor to ReactOS, wrote a good paper on the topic of VB decompilation quite a while ago. Here the [direct link to the PDF](http://web.archive.org/web/20071020232030/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf) (originally from `http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf`).

The paper documents the structures and constants of the file format itself and probably goes a long way in accompanying the information on [the opcode list from the other answer](http://web.archive.org/web/20101127044116/http://vb-decompiler.com/pcode/opcodes.php?t=1).

Answer (score 12):

They are some tools can be useful in reversing p-code binary

**vb-decompiler lite (free ver)**: very good decompiler can be download from [vb-decompiler official site](http://www.vb-decompiler.org/)

**P32Dasm**: another p-code decompiler [see here](http://progress-tools.x10.mx/p32dasm.html)
and see below of page how they debug p-code with IDA

**WKTVBDE**: p-code debugger, I don't work with it but good to try, to download search tuts4you.com site

Answer (score 6):

A very comprehensive resource on the p-code was on the site of vb vb-decompiler. Luckily there is a backup in the wayback machine, link [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101127044116/http://vb-decompiler.com/pcode/opcodes.php?t=1).